# Multiple forms from database in a single Golang web template

Tags: html, go, web

I'm doing my first project in Golang, and I'm trying to create a form with two lists to choose options from, as following:

[webpage with a form, it has two lists to choose options from and a text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKmzn.png)

However, If I want to make those lists to retrieve their entries from two tables from a SQLite database, the module "templates" only allows me to send one query per template, something like

```
func Person(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db := ConnectDB()
    arrP := GetPerson(db)
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "person", arrP)
}
```

Thus, only the first list will pull up information from the range (in this particular case, it'll display valid options from the 'person' table, and the second list will keep showing the entries I hard coded myself.

---

Thanks @Zombo for replying. To clarify some things, the function I posted opens up the connection with the database

```
db := ConnectDB()
```

Then it creates arrP (array of 'person' type) and calls the built-in *templates.ExecuteTemplate()*

```
templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "person", arrP)
```

Which will render the "person" html template. However, in that same page I'm trying to put another selection form to choose 'Service'. If I try something like

```
func Person(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db := ConnectDB()
    arrP := GetPerson(db)
    arrS := GetService(db)
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "person", arrP, arrS)
}
```

It will complain because I'm passing more arguments than expected. Therefore, only the list of persons will render properly with the information from the database; however, the list of services doesn't have any source to pull its entries from.

Comment: @Zombo specifically this line
   templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "person", arrP)
It renders the template and passes the array of 'persons' arrP so each value in that range can be displayed as an option for the selection form. The problem is if try to do something like
   templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "person", arrP, arrS)
It complains because it only will take three arguments, so the array with the list of services 'arrS' cannot be passed to the template to use it in the second list.

Comment: Use map[string]any{“arrP”: arrP, “arrS”: arrS} as the template data argument.  Use $.arrS in the template to get arrS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Zombo gave a neat answer, using a *map* we can pass multiple arrays to a template to render several list / tables.

```
map[string]any{“arrP”: arrP, “arrS”: arrS}
```

And then use *$.arrS* in the .tmpl file.